# K and R exercise 1-24

Tags: c, escaping, kernighan-and-ritchie, kr-c

I am doing programs in The C Programming Language by Kernighan and Ritchie.

I am currently at exercise 1-24 that says:

> Write a program to check a C Program for rudimentary syntax errors
>   like unbalanced parentheses, brackets and braces. Don't forget about
>   quotes, both single and double, `escape sequences`, and comments.

I have done everything well... But I am not getting how `escape sequences` would affect these parentheses, brackets and braces?

Why did they warned about escape sequences?

Comment: Don't count `\"` as part of the syntax?

Comment: `char excerpt[] = "\"Aha!\" he said.";`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `"\""`, there are three double quote characters, but still it's a valid string literal. The middle `"` is escaped, meaning the outer two balance each other. Similarly, `'\''` is a valid character literal.

Parentheses, brackets and braces are not affected, unless of course they appear in a string literal that you don't parse correctly because of an escaped quote.

Comment: `Parentheses, brackets and braces are not affected.`




-That is what I wanted! Thanks!!!

Comment: @SAM: `Parentheses, brackets and braces are not affected.` Except when they are within a pair of quotes, in which case, they should be ignored for syntax checking purposes.

Answer (score 3):

I'd guess they mean that you need to differentiate between `"` (which starts or ends a string) and `\"` (which is a `"` character, possibly inside a string)

This is important if you're to avoid reporting e.g. `strlen("\")");` as having unbalanced parentheses.

Answer (score 2):

The obvious possibility would be an escaped quote inside a string. If you don't take the escape into account, you might think the string ended there. For example: `"\")\""`. The `)` is part of the string literal, so it doesn't count as a mis-matched parenthesis.